# Parsing JSON to Excel using VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I'm having some trouble with parsing JSON data in VBA. I have tried all of the examples online but I'm still unable to solve the issue. What I have managed to do is pull the JSON data into excel in the original format using another VBA code that pulled in data from another website. I've pasted the code that works below. It's not very clean and it has some duplication because I was just trying to see if I could pull the data. 
All of the attempts I have tried to use VBA to parse the data have failed with a variety of errors depending on the approach I took. I'd be very grateful if someone could give me some advice on the simplest way to parse the data I've managed to pull. All I need is the data in columns which I can then use in other sheets in the worbook. I've attached a picture of the data that I've pulled. I have managed to parse JSON data from another webpage and in the code I included each column heading for the JSON data. For this new webpage, the JSON data is nested and there are loads of unique rows so I've not taken this approach. Many thanks

```
[Sub JSONPull()
Dim WB As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, qtb As QueryTable
Dim FC As String, sDate As String, eDate As String, Dockmasterurl As String, Performance As Worksheet

Set WB = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set ws = WB.Sheets("Control")

FC = ws.Range("B5")
sDate = ws.Range("B14")
eDate = ws.Range("B15")
Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()
    Dim vResult

Dockmasterurl = "https://fc-inbound-dock-execution-service-eu-eug1-dub.dub.proxy.amazon.com/appointment/bySearchParams?warehouseId=" & FC & "&clientId=dockmaster&localStartDate=" & sDate & "T00%3A00%3A00&localEndDate=" & eDate & "T08%3A00%3A00&isStartInRange=false&searchResultLevel=FULL"

Set ws2 = Sheets("JSON")
ws2.Cells.ClearContents

Set qtb = ws2.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & Dockmasterurl, ws2.Range("A1"))
With qtb
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

ws2.Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, textqualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, consecutivedelimiter:=False, comma:=True, trailingminusnumbers:=True
ws2.Range("A:S").EntireColumn.AutoFit

For Each qtb In ws2.QueryTables
    qtb.Delete

Next

End Sub][1]
```

Comment: You've not included any screenshot of your JSON. We'd need *at least* that or a working URL, or a sample of your JSON pasted as text. The best way to parse JSON in VBA is to use (eg) https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON  There are plenty of examples of using that here on SO alone. See  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba-json  I would recommend trying out that approach, and if you run into problems post back with your code and a description of exactly what's going wrong when you run your code.

Comment: sample of json as text and link to pastebin of full json if possible (external links generally frowned upon - at own risk if people use)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've pasted the full JSON here: https://pastebin.com/hA2UEDXy

I've tried using the github tool and get Runtime Error 424 object required on line : ReDim Values(Parsed("values").Count, 3)

Comment: Not to derail things, but have you considered using Power Query for this? (I think it's been a part of Excel on Windows since Excel 2013). It supports GET requests and JSON and you can (to some degree) visually explore/navigate the deserialised response. It will likely load the transformed/accumulated result as a table though (which you can refresh in the future).

Comment: Yes I've tried using power query but I've been unable to get the required data into columns, which I think may be due to the nested JSON data and the high number of unique rows.

Comment: It is very nested. What info do you actually need and in what format? Explore it [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a883b85fc9d44833b9467f3981844967)   Don't know what _Parsed_ is, but there are no keys called "values" in the json.  Also, have a read of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+user%3A9912714+is%3Aanswer)

Answer (score 3):

Here is VBA example showing how the [JSON sample by the link](https://pastebin.com/raw/hA2UEDXy) can be converted to 2D array and output to worksheet. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Retrieve JSON content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://pastebin.com/raw/hA2UEDXy", True
        .send
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    ' Parse JSON sample
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": End
    ' Convert JSON to 2D Array
    JSON.ToArray vJSON("AppointmentList"), aData, aHeader
    ' Output to worksheet #1
    Output aHeader, aData, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub Output(aHeader, aData, oDestWorksheet As Worksheet)

    With oDestWorksheet
        .Activate
        .Cells.Delete
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .Resize(1, UBound(aHeader) - LBound(aHeader) + 1).Value = aHeader
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
                    UBound(aData, 1) - LBound(aData, 1) + 1, _
                    UBound(aData, 2) - LBound(aData, 2) + 1 _
                ).Value = aData
        End With
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

The output for me is as follows (click to enlarge):

[image: output]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: what on earth is going on in the parser that the module code above can be so concise?! +