# Extract Data from HTML Table Using VBA

Tags: html, vba, extract

I am trying to extract data from HTML tables like the one at the site in the code below and am not sure what I'm doing wrong as I am not familiar with HTML classes, elements, etc. I found some code that reportedly worked, however I did not have access to visit the site provided so could not fully test. Code I am trying to run is below, any help would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim oDom As Object: Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim oRow As Object, oCell As Object
Dim data

y = 1: x = 1

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.nascar.com/results/racecenter/2021/nascar-cup-series/cook-out-southern-500", False
    .send
    oDom.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

With oDom.getElementsByTagName("race-center-entry-list race-center-lineup")(0)
    ReDim data(1 To .Rows.Length, 1 To .Rows(1).Cells.Length)
    For Each oRow In .Rows
        For Each oCell In oRow.Cells
            data(x, y) = oCell.innerText
            y = y + 1
        Next oCell
        y = 1
        x = x + 1
    Next oRow
End With
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
End Sub
```

Comment: "race-center-entry-list race-center-lineup" is not a valid HTML tag name

Comment: ... maybe try `getElementsByClassName` instead

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've abandoned this method and moved on to a simple copy-paste using IE. When I perform the 'select all' and 'copy' commands manually (right click the open web page) I can manually use paste special to get the data to Sheet1 in HTML, Unicode Text, or Text formats. However when I automate using the code I get several blank, selected cells at the top of Sheet1. Any ideas?

Comment: 'Sub Test()

    Dim IE As Object

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000").ClearContents


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "https://www.nascar.com/standings/nascar-cup-series/"
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        End With

        IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
        IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        IE.Quit

End Sub'

Comment: you can get all the data from this endpoint `https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2021/1/5078/weekend-feed.json` - you will need a json parser to handle the response. The data you want is dynamically retrieved by the webpage and not present in the response you are currently getting.

Comment: @QHarr this is great! I've done a great deal of searching/experimenting but I can't make the next leap... the JSON file has all of the information I'm interested in and I can manually parse online, but I would like to automate this and eventually pull the data to Excel for charting/analysis. So far I've tried writing the JSON response to a variable (VBA), dumping to a text file (batch script), and saving to a .JSON locally to allow a power query (Excel). Any ideas how to do any of these or another way to get the data to Excel (even if it isn't parsed or organized)? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You can use JsonConverter.bas (lots of examples incl. [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsonconverter.bas+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer). Also, user OmegaStripes wrote an awesome parser [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649256/parsing-json-to-excel-using-vba/57650436#57650436)  If you are familiar with other languages or powerquery/PowerBI you might also try using those. Some tooling will unravel all the json for you others you will need to study the json in a viewer and write custom code.  You can initially grab the file with a xmlhttp request or winhttp.