# Integration of web API into Excel using Macro & VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

I have used link - [Parsing JSON to Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649256/parsing-json-to-excel-using-vba)
to solve my problem, but it is not resolved fully.
Up to JSON Parse it is working as expected then not able to convert it into 2D Array & that's why not able convert JSON data into Excel table.

using code as below,

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAPI_Data()
    
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim sJSONStringTmp1 As String
    Dim sJSONStringTmp2 As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Retrieve JSON content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://pastebin.com/raw/Zp0mFEqd", True
        .send
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        sJSONString = "{ ""EmployeeDetails"": " + .responseText + "}"
        
        Debug.Print sJSONString
    End With

    Debug.Print sJSONString
    ' Parse JSON sample
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": End
    ' Convert JSON to 2D Array
    JSON.toArray vJSON("EmployeeDetails"), aData, aHeader
    ' Output to worksheet #1
    Output aHeader, aData, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub Output(aHeader, aData, oDestWorksheet As Worksheet)

    With oDestWorksheet
        .Activate
        .Cells.Delete
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .Resize(1, UBound(aHeader) - LBound(aHeader) + 1).Value = aHeader
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
                    UBound(aData, 1) - LBound(aData, 1) + 1, _
                    UBound(aData, 2) - LBound(aData, 2) + 1 _
                ).Value = aData
        End With
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

My JSON Data as follows,

```json
{
    "EmployeeDetails": "[{\"AccountName\":\"CWT COMMODITIES (ANTWERP) N.V.\",\"AccountOwner\":null,\"Age\":\"257\",\"AgreementLevel\":null,\"Amount\":\"1\",\"Amount_converted\":\"1.13\",\"Amount_converted_Currency\":null,\"AmountCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"CloseDate\":\"2022-06-15\",\"CloseMonth\":null,\"CoreTechnology\":null,\"CreatedDate\":\"2021-10-01T07:52:36.000+0000\",\"CustomerIndustry\":\"Infrastructure / Transport\",\"District\":null,\"ePSFBranch_Location\":null,\"ExclusiveHBSTechnology\":null,\"ExpectedProjectDuration\":null,\"FiscalPeriod_Num\":\"6\",\"FiscalYear\":\"2022\",\"ForecastCategory\":\"Pipeline\",\"FPXBranch\":null,\"GrossMargin_Percentage\":null,\"Industry\":\"Education\",\"IndustryCode\":null,\"LeadSource\":null,\"LegacyOpportunityNumber\":null,\"LineofBusiness\":null,\"NextSteps\":null,\"OpportunityName\":\"CWT Onderhoud BRANDDETECTIE\",\"OpportunityOwner\":\"Wim Hespel\",\"OpportunityType\":null,\"OwnerRole\":\"Direct EUR VSK&TTG Sales\",\"PrimarySolutionFamily\":null,\"PrimarySubSolutionFamily\":null,\"Probability_Percentage\":\"5\",\"ProjectEndDate\":\"2022-06-15\",\"ProjectStartDate\":\"2022-06-15\",\"RecordType\":\"Core\",\"Region\":\"Europe\",\"SalesRegion\":\"Belgium & Luxembourg\",\"Stage\":\"1.First Calls\",\"SubRegion\":\"HBS Benelux\",\"OpportunityNumber\":\"0001458471\",\"VerticalMarket\":\"Infrastructure / Transport excluding Airports\",\"Win_LossCategory\":null,\"Win_LossReason\":null,\"Country\":\"Belgium\",\"InitiatedCPQEstimateProcess\":\"False\",\"LastModifiedDate\":\"2022-03-17T15:27:33.000+0000\",\"LocationSS\":null,\"OpportunityCurrency\":null,\"OpportunityID\":\"0065a0000109AMQAA2\",\"OpportunitySubType\":null,\"OwnerID\":\"0051H00000AvuQ2QAJ\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"0121H000001eZ9VQAU\",\"CustomerType\":\"Existing Customer\",\"GBE\":\"HBS\",\"EditedBy\":\"\",\"Field_Or_Event\":\"\",\"OldValue\":\"\",\"NewValue\":\"\",\"EditDate\":\"\",\"LastStageChangeDate\":null,\"StageDuration\":null,\"ExpectedRevenue\":\"0.05\",\"GrossMarginAtSubmission\":null,\"LastActivity\":null,\"OwnerEID\":\"H185118\"}]"
}
```

**Error:**
*1] on local machine I am getting error in JSON.toArray i.e. not able to create 2D array.
2] while using above code with online JSON Data as per URL then getting only 2 column data which is not proper.*

**Updated Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAPI_Data()
    
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim sJSONStringTmp1 As String
    Dim sJSONStringTmp2 As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim s
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Retrieve JSON content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://pastebin.com/raw/Zp0mFEqd", True
        .send
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        'sJSONString = "{ ""EmployeeDetails"": " + .responseText + "}"
        sJSONString = .responseText
        Debug.Print sJSONString
    End With

    ' Parse JSON sample
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": End
    Debug.Print vJSON.Item("EmployeeDetails")
    
   'vJSON("EmployeeDetails") = "{ ""EmployeeDetails"": " + vJSON("EmployeeDetails") + "}"
    s = vJSON("EmployeeDetails")
    
    s = "{""data"":" & s & "}"
    
    
     Debug.Print vJSON.Item("EmployeeDetails")
     
    Dim xJSON As Dictionary
    'JSON.Parse vJSON("EmployeeDetails"), xJSON, sState
    JSON.Parse s, xJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": End
     
    
    ' Convert JSON to 2D Array
    JSON.toArray xJSON, aData, aHeader
    ' Output to worksheet #1
    Output aHeader, aData, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub Output(aHeader, aData, oDestWorksheet As Worksheet)

    With oDestWorksheet
        .Activate
        .Cells.Delete
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .Resize(1, UBound(aHeader) - LBound(aHeader) + 1).Value = aHeader
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
                    UBound(aData, 1) - LBound(aData, 1) + 1, _
                    UBound(aData, 2) - LBound(aData, 2) + 1 _
                ).Value = aData
        End With
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Note : I have updated API with multiple line of JSON

**Error:**
1] Now I am getting required data.
2] But the main issue is, it is coming only in 2 rows (1 for column header & other one for Data)
3] Requirement is, it should display 5 different rows with first row of header

Please help me out from this.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) and You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). • Note that you need to show the code you used (a link to a similar code is not enough) or an [mcve] and you need to explain much more detailed what **exactly** is going wrong, which errors you get or what your code does versus what you expect it to do. • Also provide an example what you expect as correct output.

Comment: Looks like your json has json as the vale for the `EmployeeDetails` property  You may need to extract that and parse it before processing the data.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ I have added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me to give a 2D array which could be placed on a worksheet:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim json As Object, s As String, recs As Object, arr
    
    Set json = ParseJson(GetContent("C:\Temp\json.txt")) 'reading from a file for testing
    s = json("EmployeeDetails")                    'get the embedded json
    Set json = ParseJson("{""data"":" & s & "}")   'parse the embedded json
    Set recs = json("data") 'collection of records 'a Collection of records
    
    arr = RecsToArray(recs)  'convert to a 2D array
    
    With Sheet6.Range("A1")
        .Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr  'write array to sheet
    End With

End Sub

'Convert an array/collection of json objects (dictionaries)
'  to a tabular 2D array, with a header row
Function RecsToArray(recs As Collection)
    Dim rec, k, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, arr()
    Dim dictCols As Object
    Set dictCols = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    i = 0
    'Collect all field names (checking every record in case some may be either incomplete or contain "extra" fields)
    '  Assumes all field names are unique per record, and no nested objects/arrays within a record
    For Each rec In recs
        For Each k In rec
            If Not dictCols.Exists(k) Then
                i = i + 1
                dictCols.Add k, i
            End If
        Next k
    Next rec
    'size the output array
    ReDim arr(1 To recs.Count + 1, 1 To i)
    'Populate the header row
    For Each k In dictCols
        arr(1, dictCols(k)) = k
    Next k
    r = 1
    'collect the data rows
    For Each rec In recs
        r = r + 1  'next output row
        For Each k In rec
            arr(r, dictCols(k)) = rec(k)
        Next k
    Next rec
    RecsToArray = arr
End Function

Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  OpenTextFile(f, 1).ReadAll()
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams Thanks lot for your precious help n time.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The very first issue you have is that you put an additional `{ "EmployeeDetails"  …json… }` around your JSON that allready has this

```
sJSONString = "{ ""EmployeeDetails"": " + .responseText + "}"
```

Don't do that!

Second issue you have is that you have a string encoded JSON inside a JSON:

So your original JSON is:

```json
{
  "EmployeeDetails": "[{\"AccountName\":\"CWT COMMODITIES (ANTWERP) N.V.\",\"AccountOwner\":null,\"Age\":\"257\",\"AgreementLevel\":null,\"Amount\":\"1\",\"Amount_converted\":\"1.13\",\"Amount_converted_Currency\":null,\"AmountCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"CloseDate\":\"2022-06-15\",\"CloseMonth\":null,\"CoreTechnology\":null,\"CreatedDate\":\"2021-10-01T07:52:36.000+0000\",\"CustomerIndustry\":\"Infrastructure / Transport\",\"District\":null,\"ePSFBranch_Location\":null,\"ExclusiveHBSTechnology\":null,\"ExpectedProjectDuration\":null,\"FiscalPeriod_Num\":\"6\",\"FiscalYear\":\"2022\",\"ForecastCategory\":\"Pipeline\",\"FPXBranch\":null,\"GrossMargin_Percentage\":null,\"Industry\":\"Education\",\"IndustryCode\":null,\"LeadSource\":null,\"LegacyOpportunityNumber\":null,\"LineofBusiness\":null,\"NextSteps\":null,\"OpportunityName\":\"CWT Onderhoud BRANDDETECTIE\",\"OpportunityOwner\":\"Wim Hespel\",\"OpportunityType\":null,\"OwnerRole\":\"Direct EUR VSK&TTG Sales\",\"PrimarySolutionFamily\":null,\"PrimarySubSolutionFamily\":null,\"Probability_Percentage\":\"5\",\"ProjectEndDate\":\"2022-06-15\",\"ProjectStartDate\":\"2022-06-15\",\"RecordType\":\"Core\",\"Region\":\"Europe\",\"SalesRegion\":\"Belgium & Luxembourg\",\"Stage\":\"1.First Calls\",\"SubRegion\":\"HBS Benelux\",\"OpportunityNumber\":\"0001458471\",\"VerticalMarket\":\"Infrastructure / Transport excluding Airports\",\"Win_LossCategory\":null,\"Win_LossReason\":null,\"Country\":\"Belgium\",\"InitiatedCPQEstimateProcess\":\"False\",\"LastModifiedDate\":\"2022-03-17T15:27:33.000+0000\",\"LocationSS\":null,\"OpportunityCurrency\":null,\"OpportunityID\":\"0065a0000109AMQAA2\",\"OpportunitySubType\":null,\"OwnerID\":\"0051H00000AvuQ2QAJ\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"0121H000001eZ9VQAU\",\"CustomerType\":\"Existing Customer\",\"GBE\":\"HBS\",\"EditedBy\":\"\",\"Field_Or_Event\":\"\",\"OldValue\":\"\",\"NewValue\":\"\",\"EditDate\":\"\",\"LastStageChangeDate\":null,\"StageDuration\":null,\"ExpectedRevenue\":\"0.05\",\"GrossMarginAtSubmission\":null,\"LastActivity\":null,\"OwnerEID\":\"H185118\"}]"
}
```

and what you get out of `vJSON.Item("EmployeeDetails")` is

```json
[
  {
    "AccountName": "CWT COMMODITIES (ANTWERP) N.V.",
    "AccountOwner": null,
    "Age": "257",
    "AgreementLevel": null,
    "Amount": "1",
    "Amount_converted": "1.13",
    "Amount_converted_Currency": null,
    "AmountCurrency": "EUR",
    "CloseDate": "2022-06-15",
    "CloseMonth": null,
    "CoreTechnology": null,
    "CreatedDate": "2021-10-01T07:52:36.000+0000",
    "CustomerIndustry": "Infrastructure / Transport",
    "District": null,
    "ePSFBranch_Location": null,
    "ExclusiveHBSTechnology": null,
    "ExpectedProjectDuration": null,
    "FiscalPeriod_Num": "6",
    "FiscalYear": "2022",
    "ForecastCategory": "Pipeline",
    "FPXBranch": null,
    "GrossMargin_Percentage": null,
    "Industry": "Education",
    "IndustryCode": null,
    "LeadSource": null,
    "LegacyOpportunityNumber": null,
    "LineofBusiness": null,
    "NextSteps": null,
    "OpportunityName": "CWT Onderhoud BRANDDETECTIE",
    "OpportunityOwner": "Wim Hespel",
    "OpportunityType": null,
    "OwnerRole": "Direct EUR VSK&TTG Sales",
    "PrimarySolutionFamily": null,
    "PrimarySubSolutionFamily": null,
    "Probability_Percentage": "5",
    "ProjectEndDate": "2022-06-15",
    "ProjectStartDate": "2022-06-15",
    "RecordType": "Core",
    "Region": "Europe",
    "SalesRegion": "Belgium & Luxembourg",
    "Stage": "1.First Calls",
    "SubRegion": "HBS Benelux",
    "OpportunityNumber": "0001458471",
    "VerticalMarket": "Infrastructure / Transport excluding Airports",
    "Win_LossCategory": null,
    "Win_LossReason": null,
    "Country": "Belgium",
    "InitiatedCPQEstimateProcess": "False",
    "LastModifiedDate": "2022-03-17T15:27:33.000+0000",
    "LocationSS": null,
    "OpportunityCurrency": null,
    "OpportunityID": "0065a0000109AMQAA2",
    "OpportunitySubType": null,
    "OwnerID": "0051H00000AvuQ2QAJ",
    "RecordTypeId": "0121H000001eZ9VQAU",
    "CustomerType": "Existing Customer",
    "GBE": "HBS",
    "EditedBy": "",
    "Field_Or_Event": "",
    "OldValue": "",
    "NewValue": "",
    "EditDate": "",
    "LastStageChangeDate": null,
    "StageDuration": null,
    "ExpectedRevenue": "0.05",
    "GrossMarginAtSubmission": null,
    "LastActivity": null,
    "OwnerEID": "H185118"
  }
]
```

Which you will need to parse again because this still is JSON!

But the converter you use does not accept the JSON to start with `[` and thats another issue here. Because if I strip that brackets off so the `[ ]` in the beginning and end are gone and parse that again it will work:

```vb
Sub GetAPI_Data()
    
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim sJSONStringTmp1 As String
    Dim sJSONStringTmp2 As String
    Dim vJSON As Dictionary
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Retrieve JSON content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://pastebin.com/raw/Zp0mFEqd", True
        .send
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        'sJSONString = "{ ""EmployeeDetails"": " + .responseText + "}" 'don't do this!
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With

    Debug.Print sJSONString
    ' Parse JSON sample

    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": End
    
    Debug.Print vJSON.Item("EmployeeDetails")
    
    Dim StripOffOuterBrackets As String
    StripOffOuterBrackets = Mid(vJSON.Item("EmployeeDetails"), 2, Len(vJSON.Item("EmployeeDetails")) - 2)
    Debug.Print StripOffOuterBrackets
    
    Dim xJSON As Dictionary
    JSON.Parse StripOffOuterBrackets, xJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": End
    
    ' Convert JSON to 2D Array
    JSON.ToArray xJSON, aData, aHeader
    ' Output to worksheet #1
    Output aHeader, aData, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub
```

And it outputs the following (and some more lines)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Peh thanks for Answer,
now its working fine but only issue is with output - last table.
My requirement is as A column should be column header (i.e. first Row) & B column is data under these headings (second row & on) like transpose of above excel table.

Comment: @MTaj well then transpose it in your output. Or use the [WorksheetFunction.Transpose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose).

Comment: Hi @Peh, Sorry to disturb you, but do last one more help please tell me how to transpose using output function, as i don't know count of data i.e. dynamic.

Comment: Note if you strip off the `[]` you may be in trouble of your API endpoint returns multiple records. That `[]` normally indicates an array of items: even though in this case there's only one item, the `[]` would be a hint there could be more...

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, Yes you are right my API may contains multiple lines up to 2000.
please suggest me solution for same

Comment: Don't strip off the outer `[]` - instead do something like  `s = vJSON("EmployeeDetails")` then `s = "{""data"":" & s & "}"` then parse `s` as JSON.

Comment: ... the resulting dictionary should then have a "data" key, with a Collection containing one dictionary per record.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I have updated question with latest used code & facing issue described over there. please pull out me from this. I have updated API Data too for multiline testing.